What is the interpretation of the word ' quickly' as used by Jesus in Jn 13:26-27?
We read in Jn 13: 26-27 (NIV):

Then he took a piece of bread, dipped it, and gave it to Judas, the son of Simon Iscariot.After he had taken the piece of bread, Satan entered him. Then Jesus told him, “Do
quickly what you are going to do "

One is intrigued by the use of 'quickly' by Jesus. Is it possible that Judas' conscience was pendulating between right and wrong of his decision to betray Jesus ? Or, was Jesus hinting to Judas that the Jewish leaders were impatiently waiting for him at the designated place? Or, did the word have yet another deeper meaning ?  What is the interpretation of the word  ' quickly' as used by Jesus ?

This statement by Jesus clearly indicates two things: [1]

That Jesus knew what Judas was about to do.

That Jesus authorized Judas to do this.



Jesus’ words to Judas: The Greek text implies an even greater immediacy with the phrase “more quickly.” So, we see that Judas’ resolve to betray Jesus is irrevocable, and his decision is as consequential as the act itself.

Jesus’ use of ‘quickly’ was a recognition of the inevitable. It
implies that since Judas’ heart was set on betrayal, and all
attempts at dissuasion had failed, he should proceed with his plan
without delay

Jesus is not merely instructing Judas to be swift; He is acknowledging the depth of Judas’ determination. The phrase “every effort to win thee has failed” is a quite tragic recognition that Judas is beyond persuasion or redemption at this point. The statement “A fixed resolve is nothing less than the deed itself” is particularly poignant, indicating that in the spiritual and moral sense, the commitment to an action is tantamount to the action being carried out.
According to Ellicott's Commentary for English Readers:

That thou doest, do quickly.—The Greek is exactly, more quickly.
“Carry out your plans even more quickly than you have proposed. Do the
fatal deed at once. It is resolved, and every effort to win thee has
failed. A fixed resolve is nothing less than the deed itself.”


Jesus spoke of His ‘hour’ not yet having come (John 2:4; 7:30; 8:20) and later, of the hour arriving (John 12:23).

Jesus’ use of ‘quickly’ was a recognition of the divine timetable. Jesus was acutely aware of the unfolding of events as part of a
divine plan and that His statement to Judas was another instance of
this awareness.
Jesus’ use of ‘quickly’ was a akin to saying, “let’s get this over with.” The following quote implies that Jesus’ words could be interpreted as an expression of resolve to face the impending events.


The Greek phrasing Jesus uses in His statement to Judas / Satan is
similar to the English phrase "hurry up." That might be another
allusion to Jesus operating according to God's divine timetable (John
2:4; 7:30; 8:20; 12:23). Or, it might be Jesus implying something to
the effect of "let's get this over with" (Luke 12:50; Matthew
26:36–39). (bibleref)


Jesus’ teachings and actions throughout the Gospels consistently demonstrate compassion and concern for the well-being of others, even those who oppose him. For instance, Jesus prays for the forgiveness of those crucifying him (Luke 23:34), and he shows concern for his mother’s care even as he is dying (John 19:26-27).

I would suggest that Jesus’ directive for Judas to act quickly was also an act of mercy. A merciful act to shorten the duration of Judas’ inner turmoil, as he was caught between his loyalty to Jesus and his plan to betray Him.


The Lord says to Judas to do what he, Judas, intended to do. But Judas intended to commit a sin of a treason of a cosmic scale. So, does the Lord in whom there is not and cannot be even a dot of sin and who got Incarnated in order to abolish sin cause Judas to sin? Absurd and blasphemous to entertain such a theory even for a second!
This excluded, then what remains?
Here’s what:
The Lord many times warned Judas not to betray Him (cf. John 6:70), even the final warning was to dip the bread in wine and to give it to Judas as a sign of loving him and even giving by this gesture a preference to him, the preference conditioned not by Judas’ merits, but by Lord’s caring for him and Lord’s trial and intent to rescue him from his treacherous intent. However, when Judas indulged in ingratitude and in abusing his free will to such an extent that even this did not help him, then the Lord told him the divinely optimal thing possible in this vile and miserable condition of his: not to linger in the sin that completely overcame him at this moment, but, since it was already unstoppable for Judas, then linger in it as shortly as possible and abandon it immediately after committing, and coming back again to Him in repentance, assuring him that He loved him so much that He was ready to forgive him this sin immediately after its fulfillment, on a necessary condition of repentance. Unfortunately, Judas did not obey Lord’s command, and after the treason committed even a greater sin of falling into a despair and giving not a chance to God to forgive and embrace him back, as He did in case of Peter, who also betrayed Him.
We are also like Judas: sometimes a sinful passion overpowers us so, that we understand that it is already impossible for us not to follow it, and like Judas, we hear a loud voice of our God and Savior Jesus Christ: “do it quickly”, that is to say, linger not in this sinful passion that you made irresistible through your flirting with it, don’t despair after having committed it, but immediately run back to Me in repentance and I will lovingly embrace you as father embraces a prodigal son”.

Amazing answer, Levan. I am afraid you have not left any scope for the other Users to answer ! But you forgot to say that Jesus washed Judas' feet .

@KadalikattJosephSibichan Thank you! Yes, indeed; and St John Chrysostom even affirms that Lord started to wash feet of apostles from Judas, because it is said that He started to wash and then came to Peter, who expressed his dread and diffidence at seeing Lord in such a servitude; but since all apostles would felt and expressed the same, then the only ungrateful apostle from whom Christ started to wash feet and who smugly and silently accepted it, Chrysostom concludes, was Judas.

Thanks, Levan . I have since posted another Question on the issue.

In John 13:27, Jesus tells Judas, "What you are going to do, do quickly." This phrase, given its brevity and urgency, indeed invites multiple interpretations. Understanding its meaning requires examining both the immediate context and Judas's complex motivations.
1. Judas’s Motivation and Jesus’s Command to Act
While some passages might suggest that Judas betrayed Jesus out of greed (e.g., John 12:6), the Gospels also provide insights into a deeper ideological rift. For instance, Judas’s objection to Mary anointing Jesus with expensive perfume (John 12:4-6) reveals that he prioritized practicality and wealth distribution—at least outwardly—as opposed to Jesus’s approval of worship and devotion. This incident likely exacerbated Judas’s disillusionment, fueling his ideological divergence. Matthew 26:15 notes that Judas went to the chief priests asking, “What are you willing to give me if I deliver him over to you?” They agree on thirty pieces of silver, a paltry amount (Exodus 21:32), which may suggest that Judas was motivated more by ideological dissatisfaction than material gain. Thus, the term “quickly” could be Jesus’s acknowledgment of Judas’s established resolve and Judas’s role in God’s redemptive plan (cf. John 17:12).
2. Jesus’s Awareness of Judas’s Internal Conflict
Jesus's command "do quickly" may also reflect an awareness of Judas's hesitation or inner turmoil. Although Satan “entered” Judas at that moment (John 13:27), implying a resolved determination, Judas’s subsequent remorse (Matthew 27:3-5) indicates he may have been wavering. Jesus, perceiving this internal conflict, could be urging Judas to make a swift decision, without allowing his conscience time to reconsider. Judas’s remorse underscores his internal struggle, as he later returns the silver and confesses, “I have sinned by betraying innocent blood” (Matthew 27:4), before taking his own life. Jesus's command thus serves as both an acceptance of Judas's predetermined role and a reminder of the gravity of Judas’s choice.
3. Jesus’s Foreknowledge of the Pharisees’ Impatience
Another possibility is that Jesus was aware that the Jewish authorities were eager to seize him before the Passover to avoid public unrest. Judas’s collaboration with them (Luke 22:2-6) required precision, as the leaders feared a public disturbance due to Jesus’s popularity (Mark 14:1-2). Jesus may have been urging Judas to act swiftly, knowing the authorities’ impatience and to fulfill the prophecy that the “Son of Man goes as it is written of him” (Matthew 26:24).
4. The Deeper Theological Meaning
On a deeper level, Jesus’s command to act “quickly” reflects the urgency and inevitability of the divine plan. Jesus’s life and mission were leading inexorably to the cross, and Judas’s role as betrayer—though tragic—was integral. Jesus knew the Father’s will (cf. John 10:17-18) and that his hour had come (John 13:1). Thus, “do quickly” encapsulates a final surrender to the unfolding events that would fulfill the prophecy (Psalm 41:9) and accomplish redemption.
Biblical References and Further Reflection

Ideological Motivation: John 12:4-6, Matthew 26:15, Exodus 21:32.
Jesus’s Awareness of Judas’s Conflict: John 13:27, Matthew 27:3-5.
Jewish Leaders’ Impatience: Luke 22:2-6, Mark 14:1-2.
Divine Foreordination: John 17:12, John 13:1, Psalm 41:9, John 10:17-18.

Jesus’s words to Judas, therefore, reflect not just a practical instruction but a multilayered acknowledgment of Judas’s inner conflict, the leaders’ urgency, and the divine orchestration behind these events.
